# 2010 SharePoint Search returns results document that doesn't contain search term

Tags: 2010, word

I am running a SharePoint 2010 search with the search criteria of "pdf".  As I would expect, I get all pdf documents in my site collection back in the Search result set.

What's interesting is that I also have a MS Word document come up in my Search results.  I opened it and search for "pdf" and nothing was found in the word document.  Even more interesting, I opened the MS Word document in Notedpad and viola I can see the phrase "pdf" in the document.

Any idea why an MS Word document would contain "pdf"?

Comment: Well what is around where it says PDF?

Comment: This question may be better served on something like the Microsoft Office Forums as it is not really SharePoint related.